# Vote count inconsistent in profile and achievements versus question itself

Tags: support, reputation, achievements-dialog, vote-count, activity

The vote count in the [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/351812/160195) itself tells me it has 2 upvotes and 0 downvotes.

---

[image]

---

But the "achievements" drop-down pane shows +8, which would typically indicate 2 upvotes and 1 downvote.

---

[image]

---

Indeed, the reputation section of my profile says 2 upvotes and 1 downvote.

---

[image]

---

I remember that prior to posting this question, I had 1990 reputation. So it looks like the downvote hasn't been counted in my reputation.

But I remember that it was counted at one point, because my reputation went from 1995 to 1993.

I was doing several edits to this question, so it's possible that the downvoter changed his/her mind and removed it or upvoted.

Does this have something to do with caching or something? I wouldn't guess that, since I'm used to votes appearing in all three places immediately.

Feel free to tag this with [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) if it's appropriate.